# String character check

Tags: c, string

i should realize two very similar functions but i am having problems.

1. I have to read the string "username", this string can only contain letters (upper and lower case) and spaces.
2. I have to read the string "key", this string can only contain letters (upper and lower case) and numbers.
   If the guidelines are not followed, the user must be able to retrieve the input.
   Unfortunately, I cannot use special libraries (only stdio and stdlib).
   I realized this:

```
    void checkString(char *i){
        int cont;
        do {
            scanf("%s", i);
            if (checkStrLen(6, 6, i) != 0) { //function that controls the size of the string (min,max,string)
                for(cont=0; cont<6;){
                    if((i[cont]>='0' && i[cont]<='9')||
                      (i[cont]>='A' && i[cont]<='Z')||
                      (i[cont]>='a' && i[cont]<='z')){
                        cont++;
                    }else{
                        printf("Not valid character");
                        printf("Try again");
                    }
            }
        }else{
            printf("\nToo large string");
            printf("\nTry again");
        }
    }while(1);
}
```

I was thinking of doing something similar.
For the first problem I would replace `(i[cont]>='0' && i[cont]<='9')` with `(i[cont]==' ')`.
the problem is that I don't understand how to get out of the for if I find a forbidden character during the loop.
I was thinking of using a break, but that would get me out of the whole function.
any advice?
PS how does the function look like? can it be okay or is it completely wrong?

Comment: Do "special libraries" include the standard C library?

Comment: If you can use `printf` and `scanf`, you should be able to use `isalnum`, etc.  But I can't understand why anyone would teach a course and allow you to use `scanf`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i can only use stdio and stdlib

Comment: Just do: `else{ printf("Not valid character"); printf("Try again"); break; }` it's not true that the `break` would get you out of the function, it breaks only the nearest loop. Anyway that `while` is an infinite loop, you need to put some exit condition in it.

Comment: @Davide I have already tried using breaks but it still doesn't work.
I'm using while (1) because until the user inserts a correct string the program must give the possibility to re-insert it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the do while loop is not necessary here. do the scanf and get user input first then call checkString. Inside checkString keep your if else statement.

```
char checkString(char *i){
        int cont;
            
        if (checkStrLen(6, 6, i) != 0) { //function that controls the size of the string (min,max,string)
                for(cont=0; cont<6;){
                    if((i[cont]>='0' && i[cont]<='9')||
                      (i[cont]>='A' && i[cont]<='Z')||
                      (i[cont]>='a' && i[cont]<='z')){
                        cont++;
                    }else{
                        printf("Not valid character");
                        printf("Try again");
                        return i;
                    }
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("\nToo large string");
            printf("\nTry again");
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that using this method if the user makes a mistake and enters an unauthorized character he cannot re-enter the string

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 100
#define SIZELIM 6
#define true    1
#define false   0

// Returns length of string
// If possible, use strlen() from <string.h> instead
int strlen(char *str) {
    char i;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != 0 && str[i] != '\n'; i++);
    return i;
}

// Returns 1 if strings are equal
// If possible, use strcmp() from <string.h> instead
int streq(const char *x, const char *y) {
    char chrx = 1, chry = 1, i;

    for (i = 0;
         chrx != 0 && chry != 0 && chrx == chry;
         chrx = x[i], chry = y[i], i++);
    return chrx == chry;
}

// Returns 1 if chr is number or letter
// If possible, use isalnum() from <ctype.h> instead
int isalnum(const char chr) {
    return (chr >= '0' && chr <= '9' ||
            chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'Z' ||
            chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'z');
}

// Checks if string contains numbers and letters only
int isvalid(const char *str) {
    int valid = true;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0 && str[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        if (!isalnum(str[i])) {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}

// Main
int main(void) {
    char str[MAXSIZE];

    for (;;) {
        printf("> ");
        fgets(str, MAXSIZE, stdin);
        if (streq(str, "quit\n"))
            break;
        if (strlen(str) > SIZELIM || !isvalid(str)) {
            if (strlen(str) > SIZELIM)
                puts("String too large");
            else if (!isvalid(str))
                puts("Not a valid string");
            puts("Try again"); }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to ask me questions about my implementation. I would have commented my explanation of each function, but it ended up taking up too much space.

Answer (score 0):

You can code those functions that you cannot import:

```
int letters_and_spaces(char c)
{
   return c == ' ' || C >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
}

int letters_and_numbers(char c)
{
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9' || C >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
}
```

And to use scanf to read spaces you can't use `%s`. You could change to:

```
scanf("%100[^\n]*c", i);
```

**BE CAREFUL**: I've put 100, supposing `i` has enough space for that. It will read up to 100 characters (or as many as the number you put there) or until find the `\n`.